# Need help restructuring SQLite database rows based on user-reordered task cards in front end

Tags: javascript, python, sqlite, fastapi

I have a task manager application where tasks are represented as rows in an SQLite database. Each task is visualized as a card on the front end, and users can reorder these cards by dragging and dropping them. However, I'm facing difficulties in persisting these changes back to the SQLite database effectively.

Here's a brief overview of how my application works:

Each task is represented as a row in the SQLite database.

On the front end, users can drag and drop task cards to rearrange their order.

I've implemented JavaScript functionality to capture the new order of tasks and send it to a
FastAPI endpoint for processing.

In the FastAPI endpoint, I attempt to update the database based on the new order received from the front end.

However, despite implementing these functionalities, the reordering of tasks doesn't reflect accurately in the database. It returns me Internal Server Error. I suspect there might be issues with my approach to updating the database rows based on the new order.

Here's what I've tried so far:

Implemented JavaScript functions to capture the new order of tasks and send it to the server.

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      const taskboards = document.getElementById('taskboard-grid');
      let selectedCard = null; // Variable to store the selected card
  
      // Event listener for double-click to select a card
      taskboards.addEventListener('dblclick', function(e) {
          if (e.target.classList.contains('task-card')) {
              if (selectedCard) {
                  // Deselect previously selected card
                  selectedCard.classList.remove('selected');
                  console.log('Deselected card:', selectedCard); // Debugging log
              }
              // Mark new selected card and add any visual indication if needed
              selectedCard = e.target;
              selectedCard.classList.add('selected');
              console.log('Selected card:', selectedCard); // Debugging log
          }
      });
  
      // Event listener for click to place the selected card before clicked card
      taskboards.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          if (selectedCard && e.target.classList.contains('task-card') && selectedCard !== e.target) {
              // Move selected card before the clicked card
              e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(selectedCard, e.target);
              selectedCard.classList.remove('selected'); // Remove selection from moved card
              console.log('Moved selected card before:', e.target); // Debugging log
              selectedCard = null; // Reset selected card variable
              updateTaskOrder(); // Call function to update order in the backend
          }
      });
  
      function updateTaskOrder() {

        if (!currentTaskboard) {
          alert("No taskboard selected.");
          return;
        }
        const tasks = document.querySelectorAll('.task-card');
        const taskOrder = Array.from(tasks)
            .map(task => task.dataset.taskId)
            .filter(taskId => taskId !== undefined); // Filter out undefined elements

        console.log(currentTaskboard)
    
        console.log(JSON.stringify({ taskBoardName: currentTaskboard, order: taskOrder }));
        fetch('/update-order', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ taskBoardName: currentTaskboard, order: taskOrder }) // Include task board name
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log('Order updated successfully'))
        .catch(error => console.error('Error updating order:', error));
    }
    
    
  });
```

Created a FastAPI endpoint to receive the new order data and update the database accordingly.

```
@app.post("/update-order")
async def update_order(data: dict):
    try:
        order = data.get('order')
        taskBoardName = data.get('taskBoardName')
        print(order, taskBoardName)
        # Assuming db is an instance of YourDatabaseClass
        db.updateTaskOrder(taskBoardName, order)
        return {"message": "Order updated successfully."}
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))





 def updateTaskOrder(self, table_name, order):
        print(table_name, order)
        with self.global_db:
            cursor = self.global_db.cursor()
            for idx, task_id in enumerate(order, start=1):
                print(idx, task_id)
                cursor.execute(f"UPDATE {table_name} SET task_order = ? WHERE id = ?", (idx, task_id))
            self.global_db.commit()
```

I tried different approaches such as using `task_order` column but for now it is not working.

I'm seeking advice on the most effective way to restructure the rows in the SQLite database based on the new order of tasks received from the front end. Are there any best practices or optimizations I should consider?

Comment: Using a `task_order` should be fine, you haven't just forgot to include  `ORDER BY task_order` in your query to retrieve have you?

Comment: I tried it yesterday, but it didn't worked, on each movement the `task_order` was changed. For example if the `task_order` is 3, after refreshing it becomes 5 (for the same card). :( :(

Comment: this looks wrong, because you aren't using the parameter you passed in: `taskBoardName = data.get('taskBoardName')` Although if you do you the parameter you passed in it looks like you are open to sql injection, since you are using an f-string in your SQL. I don't understand your last comment. You are saying task_order is changing? But it is supposed to be changing, right? - so that doesn't make sense. Similarly, if a task order changes from 3 to 5 that could be a legitimate change (for example, if it was three, and you moved it to 5).

Comment: A database table is conceptually an *unordered* collection of rows. If you need a specific order, that what `ORDER BY` in queries is for.